# Why is "Nous sommes" used for days of the week?

Tags: usage, indications-de-temps

I've just been curious about this. Why is it that saying a day of the week, something like "It's monday" uses 'nous'? as in:

> Nous sommes lundi.

Am I able to say it another way? is using:

> Aujourd'hui c'est lundi. / C'est lundi.

an acceptable format for a day of the week?
Furthermore, if that's the case, can I use

> On est lundi.

in less formal contexts?
I just want to know which of these is correct to use, and why it is that 'nous' is used pour les jours de la semaine.

Merci!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***Nous sommes lundi*** is a slightly formal/written way to tell which day of the week it is. One can also say ***Nous sommes [le] lundi premier septembre***.

This French idiom can only be used in the first person plural.
You can't say ***<s>Je suis</s> lundi*** or ***<s>ils sont</s> lundi*** because the current weekday is expected to be the same for everyone.

The same idiom exists in Spanish: ***Estamos a lunes*** and Italian: ***Siamo [a] lunedì***.

In English, while "**We are Monday**" will sound very foreign, one can say "**We are late**", "**We are on time**" or "**We are in September**" which are close.

***Aujourd'hui, c'est lundi*** or simply ***c'est lundi*** are fully acceptable equivalents.

***On est lundi*** is a less formal and more common way to say ***nous sommes lundi***.

Comment: Just a comment, in Spanish it would be "Estamos a lunes" :)

Comment: @rafabaiona      ¡ claro ! Ser y estar ...

Comment: In German we say "Wir haben Montag" (literally: we have Monday), also only in first person plural (even if it's just one person talking to themselves).

Answer (score 1):

I would say "Aujourd'hui c'est lundi. / C'est lundi." and "On est lundi." are the two best way of saying it.

"Aujourd'hui c'est lundi. / C'est lundi." is the most formal way and "On est lundi." is a bit less formal, but still very appropriate.

I personally never used "Nous sommes lundi." and don't recall ever hearing or even reading it.

Comment: About your last point, you might probably not be used to the French as it is spoken and written in France.

Answer (score 0):

Think of

> Nous sommes lundi.

as

> We are monday.

(which in fact is the word for word translation as you already know)
as in

> We are ***on a monday day*** and on this day we do laundry.

Both

> Aujourd'hui c'est lundi. / C'est lundi.

and

> On est lundi.

are correct as well. And the last one is indeed less formal as it uses *on* instead of *nous*

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation might be the underlying idea "Nous sommes arrivés à lundi (dans la série des jours de la semaine).